# Python multiprocessing: TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I am attempting to download a whole ftp directory in parallel.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import datetime
import os
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
from ftplib import FTP
curYear=""
remotePath =""
localPath = ""

def downloadFiles (remotePath,localPath):
        splitted = remotePath.split('/');
        host= splitted[2]
        path='/'+'/'.join(splitted[3:])
        ftp = FTP(host)
        ftp.login()
        ftp.cwd(path)
        filenames =  ftp.nlst()
        total=len(filenames)
        i=0
        pool = Pool()
        for filename in filenames:
                        local_filename = os.path.join(localPath,filename)
                        pool.apply_async(downloadFile, (filename,local_filename,ftp))
                        #downloadFile(filename,local_filename,ftp);
                        i=i+1

        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        ftp.close()

def downloadFile(filename,local_filename,ftp):
        file = open(local_filename, 'wb')
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, file.write)
        file.close()

def getYearFromArgs():
        if len(sys.argv) >= 2 and sys.argv[1] == "Y":
                year = sys.argv[2]
                del sys.argv[1:2]
        else:
                year = str(datetime.datetime.now().year)
        return year

def assignGlobals():
        global p
        global remotePath
        global localPath
        global URL
        global host
        global user
        global password
        global sqldb
        remotePath = 'ftp://ftp3.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/isd-lite/%s/' % (curYear)
        localPath = '/home/isd-lite/%s/' % (curYear)

def main():
        global curYear
        curYear=getYearFromArgs()
        assignGlobals()
        downloadFiles(remotePath,localPath)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

But I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 225, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

If I comment out this line:

```
pool.apply_async(downloadFile, (filename,local_filename,ftp)
```

and remove the comment on this line:

```
downloadFile(filename,local_filename,ftp);
```

Then it works just fine but it is slow and not multithreaded.

Comment: This code doesn't run as written (there are variable name errors in `downloadFiles`).  Can you post working code and show a sample call of `downloadFiles` that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Alright - I revised my post.

Comment: try: `from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool` that uses threads instead of processes as a quick workaround if it works then the issue might be in initialization/passing some objects e.g., `ftp` to child processes. Wrap `downloadFile()` body in `try/except` block to log exceptions in case this version of `multiprocessing` incorrectly reports them.

Comment: Is this happening in the first thread itself, can you try putting a print inside `downloadFile()` and see.

Answer (score 23):

**Update, May 9, 2014:**

I have determined the precise limitation. It is possible to send objects across process boundaries to worker processes as long as the objects can be pickled by [Python's pickle facility](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). The problem which I described in my original answer occurred because I was trying to send a file handle to the workers. A quick experiment demonstrates why this doesn't work:

```
>>> f = open("/dev/null")
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.dumps(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1374, in dumps
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle file objects
```

Thus, if you're encountering the Python error which led you to find this Stack Overflow question, make sure all the things you're sending across process boundaries can be pickled.

**Original answer:**

I'm a bit late to answering. However, I ran into the same error message as the original poster while trying to use Python's multiprocessing module. I'll record my findings so that anyone else who stumbles upon this thread has something to try.

In my case, the error occurred because of what I was trying to send to the pool of workers: I was trying to pass an array of file objects for the pool workers to chew on. That's apparently too much to send across process boundaries in Python. I solved the problem by sending the pool workers dictionaries which specified input and output filename strings.

So it seems that the iterable that you supply to the function such as `apply_async` (I used `map()` and `imap_unordered()`) can contain a list of numbers or strings, or even a detailed dictionary data structure (as long as the values aren't objects).

In your case:

```
pool.apply_async(downloadFile, (filename,local_filename,ftp))
```

`ftp` is an object, which might be causing the problem. As a workaround, I would recommend sending the parameters to the worker (looks like `host` and `path` in this case) and let the worker instantiate the object and deal with the cleanup.

Comment: You seriously can't map objects to functions with multiprocessing?

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact limitations are. What I described is what solved my problem.

Comment: Yeah I had to do a work around too just like you (only I ended up using threads instead). Is this limitation due to the GIL? I'm thinking if Python was thread safe it could do this.

Comment: I figured it out today-- you can send anything across process boundaries as long as it can be pickled. I'll update my answer to include this information.

Comment: I am trying to get randints from my parallel engines, just doing apply_async(np.random.randint, 5) but get the same error. What part is not pickling here?

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye: You're specifying a second parameter of simply 5. You might need to declare it as a list, e.g., (5, ), if I'm reading the docs correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
pool.apply_async(downloadFile, args=(filename,local_filename,ftp))
```

The prototype is :

```
apply_async(func, args=(), kwds={}, callback=None)
```