# TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found - Multiprocessing Pool not working in Zope/Plone external methods

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-2.6, zope

I'm using

```
Zope - 2.13.19
Python - 2.6.8
```

The below piece of code works when run manually but not when in External method.
It throws the following error. Am I doing something conceptually wrong ?

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 225, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found


import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
import logging


def func(name):
    print 'hello %s,' % name
    time.sleep(5)
    print 'nice to meet you.'


def get_data():
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    pool.map(func, ('frank', 'justin', 'osi', 'thomas'))
```

Comment: What do you mean by `External Method`?

Comment: In Zope, you don't have access to all of Python features because it uses something called as Restricted Python. Hence, to take full advantage of Python's capabilities, you write External methods which the scripts written in RestrictedPython can access. For example, it would not be possible to write from multiprocessing in RestrictedPython script because of security restrictions. So we create an external method to do the imports and then call it from RestrictedPython script.

Comment: Maybe you used another Python for the manual testing than the one ZOPE uses? Assuming external means the script is located somewhere inside `[ZOPE_DIRECTORY]/parts`, I'd go for pouring it into an own add-on and call it via a browser-view for the import-form.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the things you're sending across process boundaries can be [pickled](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).

As stated by [Multimedia Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751395/5675325):

> It is possible to send objects across process boundaries to worker
> processes as long as the objects can be pickled by Python's pickle
> facility.